# Custom flag marked as helpful, but nothing changed

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-answers, code-only-answers, custom-flags

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423853/pivot-deleted-event-when-parent-is-deleted/60425568#60425568) caught my eye because it had nothing whatsoever to do with the question. When I investigated, I found this user has posted the same answer to at least a dozen questions. I raised a custom flag:

> This user seems to have a habit of posting code-only answers to numerous questions at once; often it is repeated code, and often with no relationship to the question. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60123486/1255289 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60068230/1255289 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116810/1255289

The flag was marked as helpful, but aside from the original answer being deleted (by the author after I downvoted) nothing seems to have happened.

This concerns me because this is not just a matter of the few questions included in my flag. [A Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Toastr%22%20%22Post%20Successfully%20Save%22%20site:stackoverflow.com) for specific terms in that answer pulled up these:

- [React Native: Upload image with fetch to Laravel
  Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59763596/1255289)
- [image upload using a postgres bytea blob field in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59764411/1255289)
- [Laravel Image Upload not saving to public folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60068230/1255289)
- [how to
  updaload image twice with diffrent
  sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244997/1255289)
- [CRUD Update
  with image Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60123486/1255289)
- [Laravel Many-to-Many - Handling relation on
  controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59754531/1255289)
- [Laravel -
  limiting users for number of
  posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59746181/1255289)
- [How can I
  insert into laravel pivot
  table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59712300/1255289)
- [Laravel
  eloquent insert data with
  relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701649/1255289)
- [Laravel
  Image resize on uploaded
  file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59873417/1255289)
- [Can't Upload
  Images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59906041/1255289)

[Another search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Toastr%22%20%22Profile%20Successfully%20Updated%22%20site:stackoverflow.com) will turn up similar patterns:

- [Laravel user update
  problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58723597/1255289)
- [Laravel 5.1 - Admin panel - Update
  User](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59992806/1255289)
- [LARAVEL 6.x = Trying to get property 'id' of
  non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59797212/1255289)
- [How to update data in
  laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59992891/1255289)
- [Laravel 5.1 - Admin panel - Update User](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59992806/1255289)

All of which are identical code-only answers by the same user, almost all of which have nothing to do with the question asked. If this isn't fraudulent or malicious somehow<sup>*</sup>, it's at least disruptive and counter to how this site is supposed to operate. What gives?

<sup>*</sup> The fact that some of these completely irrelevant answers are upvoted or accepted suggests possible sockpuppets to me.

Comment: downvote it. It will at least trigger the *ban* if many other users do the same.

Comment: I can only downvote 2 a day without being flagged by the system as a serial downvoter. And it doesn't stop the user from continuing this behaviour.

Comment: There seems to be a history with that user. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122046/crud-update-with-image-laravel) is a answer that has been deleted by a mod 25 days ago with a comment that the user shouldn't do that anymore. 5 minutes later that user reposted the same answer to the question. Might have been marked as helpful because the problem was discussed with the user already?

Comment: @BDL I would hope the user was contacted by a mod, but of course I have no way to know, unless it goes as far as a suspension. My main concern is why these dozen identical, irrelevant, code-only answers weren't deleted.

Comment: Our bad. We will remember to mark all of your flags as declined in the future in order to avoid this problem. :-)

Comment: Uh oh I'm on the blacklist now!

Comment: They even post the same answer twice on the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116945/2029983). I must admit, considering every one is a copy and paste, they can't even be correct on most of them; as there will be some nuance that makes it different in the question.

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60359565/2029983). Seems they don't know the [edit] link exists.

Comment: @CodyGray ^^^ if I remember correctly, there is a suspension reason "for low quality contributions"

Comment: Considering the reputation the OP has lost, I felt it would be wise to [let them know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60122046/crud-update-with-image-laravel/60123486#comment107123708_60123486) that they are being discussed on meta.

Comment: @Larnu looking forward to them coming to meta and posting a code block about resizing images in response.

Comment: If they do, @miken32 I really hope that a moderator maybe does something more reactive. :)

Comment: So @CodyGray I take from the lack of (serious) response that nothing's going to happen?

Comment: @miken32 looks like the OP has deleted a lot of their posts